# Access database query locks ability to edit table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I created a query in Microsoft Access like the one below:

```
SELECT Deliverables.ID, Deliverables.Title, Deliverables.Summary, 
Deliverables.Header_Code, Deliverables.Header_Code.Value, Deliverables.Sort_order, 
Deliverables.Pillar, Deliverables.Pillar.Value, Deliverables.Misc_ID
FROM Deliverables
WHERE (((Deliverables.Pillar.Value)="Link Building"));
```

But my problem is that this query locks my fields and I cannot make changes to the table using the query view.

Any suggestions?  I am using Microsoft Access 2007

Comment: Looks like Header_Code and Pillar are multi-value fields.  Can you confirm?

Comment: Multivalue fields should be avoided unless you need them for compatibility with Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very experienced with multi-value fields.  However, I experimented with it a little, and I think the fields in your query might be editable if you can eliminate Header_Code.Value and Pillar.Value from your output field list.  Can this version work for you?

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Title, d.Summary, d.Header_Code, d.Sort_order, d.Pillar, d.Misc_ID
FROM Deliverables AS d
WHERE (((d.Pillar.Value)="Link Building"));
```